# Explicitly close a OGR result object from a call to ExecuteSQL

Tags: python, ogr, spatialite

How can I explicitly close/release the result of an ExecuteSQL statement when querying a Spatialite database with OGR via Python?  I have a simple query to return the SRID of a dataset.  This works as expected.  However, subsequent calls to `ds.ExecuteSQL` fail with the error 'SQL logic error or missing database' unless I iterate all the way through the result rows.

For example:

```
ogr.UseExceptions()

# This query returns a single row
sql = 'select distinct srid(geometry) from foo'
result = ds.ExecuteSQL(sql)
row = result.next()
epsg = row.GetField(0)

# This call fails
ds.ExecuteSQL('drop table bar')
```

Completing the iteration avoids the error:

```
_ = [r for r in result]
```

This is fine for simple cases, but not very explicit.  I've tried calling `result.Dereference()`, `row=None; result=None` but these do not help.  What is it that I'm missing here?

**UPDATE**
The exception is only raised when I enable ogr.UseExceptions().  Otherwise the error passes silently and the drop table statement has no affect.

Comment: hmmm. i was able to run a test case without issue - using 2 different select statements. Is it because the second statement in your example is a drop table command?

Comment: @fluidmotion You may be on to something.  I suspect OGR is expecting a return value that is not present for the drop table.  Note that I am explicitly requesting OGR Exceptions to be raised.

Comment: at risk of asking a simple question - is the datasource capable of deleting the table? it can be tested with print ds.TestCapability('oDsCDeleteLayer'). In my test case, this returned false (see http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql.html 'The OGR SQL DROP TABLE command can be used to delete a table. This is only supported on datasources that declare the ODsCDeleteLayer capability.')

Comment: TestCapability returned False.  However, if I execute the drop table before the select everything works.  My understanding from the SQLite/Spatialite OGR driver docs is that all SQL statements are passed directly to the SQLite engine unless the dialect is specified as `OGR_SQL`. Also, in this case the table being dropped is a simple table with no geometry columns.

Comment: ok - not to grasp at straws, but the ogr_sql page also mentions '[after ExecuteSQL] The returned temporary layer should be released with OGRDataSource::ReleaseResultsSet() method when no longer needed. Failure to release it before the datasource is destroyed may result in a crash.' Sorry - i haven't had a chance to test.

Answer (score 6):

As @fluidmotion suggested the result layer object returned by `result=ds.ExecuteSQL(sql)`, with a select statement that returns rows, must be released by calling `ds.ReleaseResultSet(result)` to properly destroy the object.  I overlooked this in the documentation, [API](http://www.gdal.org/classGDALDataset.html#a5b65948b1e15fa63e96c0640eb6c5d7c) and [OGR_SQL](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql.html).

```
ogr.UseExceptions()

# This query returns a single row
sql = 'select distinct srid(geometry) from foo'
result = ds.ExecuteSQL(sql)
row = result.next()
epsg = row.GetField(0)

# Destroy the result set
ds.ReleaseResultSet(result)

# This call should now succeed
ds.ExecuteSQL('drop table bar')
```