# Convert total area calculation from ogrinfo (cli) to python ogr

Tags: python, gdal, ogr

How can I do this command ([source](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/232902/calculate-total-area-of-polygons-in-shapefile-using-gdal/232907#232907)):

```
ogrinfo -q -sql "SELECT SUM(OGR_GEOM_AREA) AS TOTAL_AREA FROM way" way.geojson
```

with Python ogr?

```
from osgeo import ogr
```

Comment: Are you aware that the result will not make much sense because GeoJSON is using long/lat degrees as units and square degree as an area unit is useless?

Comment: Is shapefile better?

Comment: The problem is in the projection, not in the format.

Comment: Don't understand me wrong, what you want to do is OK and you can do it with Python and executeSQL like in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/114112/explicitly-close-a-ogr-result-object-from-a-call-to-executesql. The result just is not useful for you. You must learn a bit about different projections and transform data into some suitable coordinate system for area measurements.